# CCM in the RUP setting reduced to CTR?

Tags: aes, authenticated-encryption, ctr, ccm

I have a question regarding the paper:

Andreeva, E. et al, Securely Release Unverified Plaintext in Authenticated Encryption , 2014
(DOI: 10.1007/978-3-662-45611-8_6)

> AE schemes such as GCM [28] and CCM [40] reduce to CTR mode in the RUP setting. This is because the adversary does not need to forge a ciphertext in order to obtain information about the corresponding (unverified) plaintext.

I cannot follow the explanation. Which ciphertext would be forced? The one used for CBC? (used in CCM as I understand it's a combination of CBC+CTR)
Can someone provide a more detailed explanation of why CCM's security reduces to CTR's security?